# ES6 | How To Export+Import Objects Here?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, export

I'm an ES6+ newbie and I'm currently building a React app but I ran into an issue - I'm trying to import 2 objects but am failing to do so. I tried various things and got errors, and when I didn't get errors in one attempt, I tried to `.toString()` a value of one of the object's properties and got an error of `undefined`.

This is file structure (ignoring irrelevant files):

```
src
├── index.js
└── style
    └── colors.js
```

Where `colors.js` is:

```
const primaryColor = {
    900: "#001a8f",
    800: "#002EA2",
    700: "#1238ae",
    600: "#1238ae",
    500: "#274ac4",
    400: "#4e66cd",
    300: "#7081d6",
    200: "#9aa5e2",
    100: "#c3c8ed",
     50: "#e7e9f8"
};
primaryColor['main'] = primaryColor[800];

const secondaryColor = {
    900: "#3c3c3c",
    800: "#606060",
    700: "#818181",
    600: "#979797",
    500: "#c2c2c2",
    400: "#dedede",
    300: "#f0f0f0",
    200: "#f5f5f5",
    100: "#fafafa",
     50: "#FFFFFF"
};
secondaryColor['main'] = secondaryColor[50];
```

And I'm not sure how `export` here.

And in `index.js` I I want to `import` both `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor`.

What are the correct/possible ways to export them and import them?
I thought I knew how to export and import but due to the errors I got I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Are you using Babel Transpiler for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const primaryColor = {
    900: "#001a8f",
    800: "#002EA2",
    700: "#1238ae",
    600: "#1238ae",
    500: "#274ac4",
    400: "#4e66cd",
    300: "#7081d6",
    200: "#9aa5e2",
    100: "#c3c8ed",
     50: "#e7e9f8"
};
primaryColor['main'] = primaryColor[800];

export const secondaryColor = {
    900: "#3c3c3c",
    800: "#606060",
    700: "#818181",
    600: "#979797",
    500: "#c2c2c2",
    400: "#dedede",
    300: "#f0f0f0",
    200: "#f5f5f5",
    100: "#fafafa",
     50: "#FFFFFF"
};
secondaryColor['main'] = secondaryColor[50];
```

and import as shown below

```
import { primaryColor, seondaryColor } from './style/colors.js'
```

Comment: Great, thank you, it worked!

Other solutions (like the answer above you and below you) didn't work for me. Do you know why this works and the others don't?

Also, where can I read about the difference of exporting a declaration compared to export an already-declared variable/function?

Comment: I saw one of the other answers, that did not work as we cannot have two default exports

Answer (score 0):

You can export from `colors.js` file like this

```
export default { primaryColor, seondaryColor };
```

And import it from `index.js` file like this:

```
import { primaryColor, seondaryColor } from './style/colors.js'
```

You can learn more about named and default import/exports here: [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Examples) [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Examples)

Comment: I already tried that.

I tried it again now and now I get an error: 
`Attempted import error: 'primaryColor' is not exported from './style/colors.js'.`

Answer (score 0):

In your `colors.js` file, do the following

```
const primaryColor = {
    900: "#001a8f",
    800: "#002EA2",
    700: "#1238ae",
    600: "#1238ae",
    500: "#274ac4",
    400: "#4e66cd",
    300: "#7081d6",
    200: "#9aa5e2",
    100: "#c3c8ed",
    50: "#e7e9f8"
};
primaryColor['main'] = primaryColor[800];

const secondaryColor = {
    900: "#3c3c3c",
    800: "#606060",
    700: "#818181",
    600: "#979797",
    500: "#c2c2c2",
    400: "#dedede",
    300: "#f0f0f0",
    200: "#f5f5f5",
    100: "#fafafa",
    50: "#FFFFFF"
};
secondaryColor['main'] = secondaryColor[50];

export { primaryColor, secondaryColor };
```

And in your `index.js`, use it like:

```
import { primaryColor, secondaryColor } from './style/colors.js';
...
primaryColorMain = primaryColor['main'];
secondaryColorMain = secondaryColor['main'];
```

---

Hope this helps!